# Checking a value exists in PHP $_SESSION fails even when the value is there

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I'm trying to check for a value in a $_SESSION variable, and if the value is present redirect the user to another page. The code is as follows:

```
// create session
session_set_cookie_params( 0,'/',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],true,true);
session_name('test');
session_start();
//  check if test session is set, if it is redirect to page-2
if (isset($_SESSION['value1']) && !empty($_SESSION['value1'])) {
    header("Location: /page-2");
    exit();
}
```

I know the value is there because when I go to the second page I can access it there like:

```
$value1 = $_SESSION['value1'];
```

What could I be doing wrong? Any help appreciated

Edit: The problem is `isset($_SESSION['value1']) && !empty($_SESSION['value1'])` seems to be returning false when I am expecting it to be true and I'm not being redirected to the second page

Session values are set on the first page after a call to an external API

Comment: Whats the problem? You seem to have left that bit out. Clarify what is happening, and what you wanted to happen. You say you got to the second page, so the redirect worked... and then you say you can access the value... confused here.

Comment: If this is about a redirection failing, enable error reporting. You could be outputting before header. Your question is unclear. Either way, enable error reporting.

Comment: you have to add this **session_name('test'); session_start();** before use $_SESSION variable

Comment: where are you setting these SESSION values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue with load balancing and was solved by configuring sticky sessions.